# How to filter an array based on an array of objects inside the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects called allLeads. Each object has another array of objects called leads. Now I have a single searchbar in which a user can type anything and I have a function that is called onChange which will check for the search value in four different items in the array - leadName which is at the top level in all objects and currentCompany, leadActivity and status which are inside the objects in the leads array. Inside the leads array, if user writes linkedin in the searchbar then only the object with currentCompany as linkedin will be returned and not the one with google. I need to somehow figure out a way to return my array objects based on these four parameters but whatever I have tried so far has failed. Please pardon me if the question is repeated as I haven't found any similar query so far.

```
//Array to search

const allLeads = [
{
leadName: 'react',
leads: [
  {
    currentCompany: 'linkedin',
    leadActivity: 'messaged',
    status: 'connected'
  },
  {
    currentCompany: 'google',
    leadActivity: 'messaged',
    status: 'not connected'
  }
],
leadId: '555',
userId: '555'
},
{
leadName: 'angular',
leads: [
  {
    currentCompany: 'walmart',
    leadActivity: 'messaged',
    status: 'connected'
  },
  {
    currentCompany: 'amazon',
    leadActivity: 'not messaged',
    status: 'not connected'
  },
],
leadId: '666',
userId: '666'
}
]
```

So far what I have tried is this but it doesn't work with filter inside the filter. Neither does it work with filter inside the map.

```
export const searchLeads = (allLeads, value) => {
 const newLeads = allLeads.filter(({ leadName, leads }) => {
  leads.filter(({ currentCompany, leadActivity, status }) => {
    return (
      filterItem(leadName, value)
      ||
      filterItem(currentCompany, value)
      ||
      filterItem(leadActivity, value)
      ||
      filterItem(status, value)
    );
  })
  return newLeads;
}
 )};

const filterItem = (item, itemToCheck) => {
if(item.toLowerCase().includes(itemToCheck.toLowerCase())) return true;
else return false;
}
```

Comment: do you have an example of the search and the wanted result?

Comment: what do you want returned if the user types 'not connected', there are more than 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet of what you need with comments
https://jsbin.com/zeyomidafa/edit?js,console

```
const allLeads = [
  {
    leadName: 'react',
    leads: [
    {
      currentCompany: 'linkedin',
      leadActivity: 'messaged',
      status: 'connected'
    },
    {
      currentCompany: 'google',
      leadActivity: 'messaged',
      status: 'not connected'
    }
    ],
    leadId: '555',
    userId: '555'
  },
  {
    leadName: 'angular',
    leads: [
      {
        currentCompany: 'walmart',
        leadActivity: 'messaged',
        status: 'connected'
      },
      {
        currentCompany: 'amazon',
        leadActivity: 'not messaged',
        status: 'not connected'
      },
    ],
    leadId: '666',
    userId: '666'
  }
]


function filter(aleads, q){
  // map the list and only keep leads matching the query
  let aleadsDeepFilter = aleads.map(
     function(oneLead){
       return {
         ...oneLead,
         leads: oneLead.leads.filter(
           function(_lead){
             return (_lead.status === q) || (_lead.leadActivity === q) || (_lead.currentCompany === q)
           }
         )
       }
     }
  );

  // second filter, return items that have leads left from previous filter + matching the leadName
  aleadsDeepFilter = aleadsDeepFilter.filter(
    function(oneLead){
      return (oneLead.leadName === q) || (oneLead.leads.length > 0)
    }
  )

  return aleadsDeepFilter;

}


console.log(filter(allLeads, "angular"))
console.log(filter(allLeads, "google"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could restructure your object? I think your complexity comes from the fact that you are organizing your objects in a very complex(nested) way.

I would be simple as:

```
simplerArrayOfObj =
[{ leadname:'whatever', currentCompany:'whatever', leadActivity:'', status:'whatever'},
{ leadname:'whatever', currentCompany:'whatever', leadActivity:'', status:'whatever'}]
```

From there is a question of:

```
   const newArrayFiltered = function search(leadname, currentCompany, leadActivity, status){
    //validate the fields first
    // ...more code
     return simplerArrayOfObj.filter(arr=> arr.leadname === leadname || arr.currentCompany === currentCompany || arr.leadActivity === leadActivity || arr.status === status)
    }
```

With this new array `newArrayFiltered`  you could do all the deep levels things you want.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.filter` will aways return an array. In the `allLeads.filter` you never return anything, so it never knows if a specific item meets that criteria.

To see if which items meet your criteria, I suggest changing `leads.filter(({ currentCompany, leadActivity, status }) => {` to `return leads.filter(({ currentCompany, leadActivity, status }) => {`

Also change `allLeads.filter(({ leadName, leads }) => {` to a map with `allLeads.map(({ leadName, leads }) => {`

That'll give you an array of arrays. If you want to flatten that out, you can use lodash or something like:

```
const flattenedArray = arrayOfArrays.reduce((acc, arr) => {
  return acc.concat(arr);
}, []);
```